Windows bat file for loop missing ! character from file name
I have this code for looping over MP4 files in a directory:
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b .\*.mp4') do (
    call :processing "%%~nxf"
)

my problem is that If the MP4 file name has the "!" character in it, the %%f value will have all characters except "!". For some reason the "!" character is getting stripped out. If you execture the dir command of the for loop directly, the "!" character prints in the shell.
Any thoughts why the "!" is missing?
thanks!

there is no hint, delayed expansion is needed, so turn it off.

You should always provide a [mcve] of the code that reproduces the problem.  By default delayed expansion is turned off.  So the only way you would get the output is if you have enabled delayed expansion at the top of your script.

Reproducible example of the problem (delayed expansion is ON) which uses !var! as the syntax for delayed expansion of environment variables.
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b .\*.mp4') do (
    call :processing "%%~nxf"
)
goto :eof
:processing
echo %1

Output:
"there.mp4"
"hi.mp4"

Disable delayed expansion to fix.  This is usually the default, but the OP code does not show one way or the other.
@echo off
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b .\*.mp4') do (
    call :processing "%%~nxf"
)
goto :eof
:processing
echo %1

Output:
"!there.mp4"
"hi!.mp4"

